# RMagick randomly orders pngs into gif

Tags: ruby, rmagick

Attempting to bundle pngs into a gif, using `ImageList` is giving seemingly random order to gif frames. [Example broken gif](https://github.com/redcodefinal/rubyfunge/blob/master/cat/cat.gif)

The images are named name-#######.png ([example directory](https://github.com/redcodefinal/rubyfunge/tree/master/cat)) and appear to be in correct order.

gif code

```
def make_gif
  snapshots.length.times do |frame|
    render_frame frame
  end
  gif = ImageList.new(*Dir["#{name}/#{name}-*.png"])
  gif.delay = 100
  gif.write("#{name}/#{name}.gif")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Dir#glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Dir.html#method-c-glob) never promised to return ordered list of filenames.

So, you should sort a list yourselves:

```
#                                         ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
ImageList.new(Dir["#{name}/#{name}-*.png"].sort)
```

Hope it helps.